# PCC-F-02044, CMD-LINE: Illegal or out of range value for option

Tags: oracle, compiler-errors, compilation, proc

I am getting this error `PCC-F-02044, CMD-LINE:  Illegal or out of range value for option`, when I run proc . What are the reasons, If any one knows solution. Please let me know?

Comment: elaborate your question please.

Comment: I a m trying to convert .pc file to c, when I run the command proc <filename.pc>, I am getting the above said error.[FYI: Pro*C is compiler used to convert .pc files to correspondent .c file ]